# How to set the output directory for exporting a pdf file with skim?

Tags: macos, finder, pdf, preview, skim

I am looking for an option (or something else) for the PDF viewer Skim (V1.6.8) on macOS (High Sierra):

After modifying a PDF file (e.g. adding a note or highlighting a part of it) Skim enables the possibility to save (export) the PDF including the embedded notes such that no additional `.skim` file is produced. Invoking **File** > **Export** for the first time a panel opens where the file including the PDF notes can be saved on disk.

Unfortunately, the suggested folder in the panel is set to the last folder used and not to the 'active' one where the PDF file is.

Does anybody know how to adjust the folder automatically in order to shorten the workflow? Of course, after a second export of the PDF file the folder is set to the right one. Is it possible to avoid this behavior?

Comment: Two simple options… drag the desired folder from the desktop to the file picker dialog, or get Default Folder X

Comment: @Tetsujin: Thx for your answer. But I do not really understand exactly what you suggest. What do you mean by 'get Default Folder X'? Is there a way that skim automatically chooses the proper folder? I mean when I work with several different folders in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a bit I found one (not yet perfect) workaround:

After opening Skim Export panel (via **File** > **Export**) **with embedded notes** option set, Cmd</kbd+Click the file name on the title bar of Skim windows. Click on the next following directory in the open panel which contains the desired folder.

A separate new Finder window opens with the content of this folder.

Drag with a left-click the folder name to the still open Skim export panel. This will immediately change the output directory accordingly (and is the idea). Now, the pdf file can be saved in the right place.